# Does this function have explicit return values on all control paths?

Tags: c++, templates, return, code-coverage

I have a [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) centered on unity for any data type, which I've encoded using:

```
template <typename T>
int h1(const T& t){
   if (t < 1){
       return 0;
   } else if (t >= 1){
       return 1;
   }
}
```

In code review, my reviewer told me that there is not an explicit return on all control paths. And the compiler does not warn me either. But I don't agree; the conditions are mutually exclusive. How do I deal with this?

Comment: `return t >= 1;` kinda gives you the same without branching...

Comment: Why not just `if (t < 1) return 0; return 1;` ?

Comment: Out of interest, why does this function need to be templatised? Are you *really* using it with different types?

Comment: I use it with a high precision floating point libary.

Comment: Right - that makes some sense then.

Comment: @StoryTeller `return t >= 1;` always compiles to a branch if the result can't be precomputed. Regardless, replacing the else if with it does indeed fix the problem.

Comment: @KobyDuck "always" on what platform? GCC on x86 [doesn't emit a branch for common types](https://godbolt.org/g/avoDzL) even with `-O0 -m32`.

Comment: @Leushenko I wasn't aware of that particular optimization, you're right. The point I was trying to make is that there's no guarantee that `return t >= 1` won't branch unless you're compiling for specific CPUs and your complier plays ball. There are CPUs that don't have branchless alternatives for every condition. AFAIK ARM falls into this category. See [GCC ARM -03](https://godbolt.org/g/4UntyX).

Comment: @KobyDuck There is no guarantee that `return a+b;` won't branch, or `return 1;` won't branch.  C++ makes zero guarantees about "will code branch".  You can eliminate branches in the abstract machine and you can use idioms that are known to compilers to emit branchless instructions when available.

Comment: @Yakk, Agreed, but one can reasonably assume a sane compiler won't emit a branch for simple code such as `return a+b` and `return 1`.

Comment: @KobyDuck _and_ reasonably sane developers, don't forget that part

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you add `if (t >= 1)`?  This is, why'd you add in extra code if you thought it didn't do anything?

Comment: consider throwing a `domain_error` in the exceptional case.

Comment: You have reviewers that care this much? Count your blessings!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you write a method that even appears to have a fall through in the first place? I'm not a C++ developer, but surely, avoiding code like this is a good habit to be in? Unless I had a *really* good reason for doing this, I'd just agree with the reviewer immediately, no questions (other than what I was thinking when I wrote it).

Comment: Since you've mentioned that you are doing this with a floating point value, you need to think about what `h1` should return for `NaN` and when the difference from 1 is `-0` (assuming your library has these)

Answer (score 230, accepted):

It depends on how the template is used. For an `int`, you're fine.

**But**, if `t` is an IEEE754 floating point `double` type with a value set to `NaN`, neither `t < 1` nor `t >= 1` are `true` and so program control reaches the end of the `if` block! This causes the function to return without an explicit value; the behaviour of which is undefined.

(In a more general case, where `T` overloads the `<` and `>=` operators in such a way as to not cover all possibilities, program control will reach the end of the `if` block with no explicit `return`.)

The moral of the story here is to decide on which branch should be the default, and make that one the `else` case.

Answer (score 13):

Just because code is correct, that doesn't mean it can't be better. Correct execution is the *first* step in quality, not the last.

```
if (t < 1) {
    return 0;
} else if (t >= 1){
    return 1;
}
```

The above is "correct" for any datatype of `t` than has sane behavior for `<` and `>=`. But this:

```
if (t < 1) {
    return 0;
}
return 1;
```

Is easier to see by inspection that every case is covered, and avoids the second unneeded comparison altogether (that some compilers might not have optimized out). Code is not only read by compilers, but by humans, including you 10 years from now. Give the humans a break and write more simply for their understanding as well.

Comment: I know what you're trying to say (have an upvote) but there is an implication here that IEEE754 types are not "sane". Is this what you meant? Also I'd love to see an example where a compiler does optimise out the second conditional check.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I don't think it's entirely unreasonable to say that `NaN` is not "sane" -  a *numeric* type with a value that is not a *number*, and hence the type is not ordered? Obviously I know why it's there: the argument isn't whether `float` *should* do such a thing, merely that it leads to nonsensical ordering operations. I suppose one could say it's unreasonable to express it that way, on account of the inherent ablism in society's common use of mental illness as an analogy for anything difficult or unexpected.

Comment: @Bathsheba I consider a [partially ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) sane (which allows `x<1` and `x>=1` to be both false), but I consider IEEE floats insane because `==` is no equivalence relation and comparison doesn't match the requirements for a partial ordering.

Comment: @Bathsheba, gcc -O2 (and -O3) removed the second comparison with integer t.

Answer (score 8):

As noted, some special numbers can be both `<` and `>=`, so your reviewer is simply right.

The question is: what made you want to code it like this in the first place? Why do you even consider making life so hard for yourself and others (the people that need to maintain your code)? Just the fact that you are smart enough to deduce that `<` and `>=` should cover all cases doesn't mean that you have to make the code more complex than necessary. What goes for physics goes for code too: make things as simple as possible, but not simpler (I believe Einstein said this).

Think about it. What are you trying to achieve? Must be something like this: 'Return 0 if the input is less than 1, return 1 otherwise.' What you've done is add intelligence by saying ... oh but that means that I return 1 if t is greater or equal 1. This sort of needless 'x implies y' is requiring extra think work on behalf of the maintainer. If you think that is a good thing, I would advise to do a couple of years of code maintenance yourself.

If it were my review, I'd make another remark. If you use an 'if' statement, then you can basically do anything you want in all branches. But in this case, you do not do 'anything'. All you want to do is return 0 or 1 depending on whether t<1 or not. In those cases, I think the '?:' statement is **much** better and more readable than the `if` statement. Thus:

`return t<1 ? 0 : 1;`

I know the `?:` operator is forbidden in some companies, and I find that a horrible thing to do. `?:` usually matches much better with specifications, and it can make code so much easier to read (if used with care) ...

Comment: I'd prefer `return !(t < 1);` or `return t >= 1;` depending on which one is the "catch all" case.

Comment: @Bathsheba While you're technically correct, since true==1 and false==0, Bert's solution remains more faithful to the OP's original, which may have been a simplified case of the real code anyway.

Comment: @Bathseba The original question shows an `int` return. You rely on implicit conversion but I like code that shows exactly what we're _intending_. If the _intention_ is to return a bool, then the return value should be a bool. Secondly, from that code, I deduce that the intention is to return `1` on the 'catch-all' branch (which of course turned out to not be that). Hence, no need to obfuscate things as a `return !(t < 1)` would do.