# Control reaches end of non void function (c++) using while loop

Tags: c++

I've already researched this but I still don't understand clearly the issue. So, I have this code:

```
int is_negative(int a)
{
    if(a < 0)
    return a;
    else while (a>=0)
    {
        cout << "Insert a negative value, please: ";
        cin >> a;
        if(a < 0)
            return a;
    }
 }
```

This function is called in the main function because I want the user to enter a negative number, and to store the value only if it's negative. If it's not, I want it to loop until a negative one is entered.

Why am I getting the error :"Control reaches end of non void function [-Wreturn-type]"? Thanks! :)

PS. I have to use simple syntax like a while or a for loop (exercise requires to do so).

Comment: Since your question is "why" and not "what can I do", I'll leave this as a comment, but I think I can help. If you start with `while(a >= 0)`, anything following that block implicitly has `a < 0`, and if `a < 0`, the loop is never entered. You can safely return your value as the closing line. If you like recursion, this wouldn't be a bad time for it; instead of looping, you can simply call the same function again: `if(a >= 0) { ...; cin >> a; return is_negative(a); } return a;`

Answer (score 6):

Problem is that compiler cannot detect that loop will never let execution flow to reach behind it, it is not that smart. On another side you could just write `while( true )` to avoid confusion.

But the best just change your function to:

```
int is_negative(int a)
{
    while (a>=0)
    {
        cout << "Insert a negative value, please: ";
        cin >> a;
    }
    return a;
 }
```

It does exactly the same, but simpler, more readable and would not confuse compiler anymore.

Note: you should check if `cin` closed and act accordingly, or you may enter infinite loop

Comment: What happens if you enter a non-digit string?

Answer (score 2):

It's only a warning and although your compiler is doing its best, you have outsmarted it on this particular occasion. Yes, the final brace is never reached.

You have three options:

1. Accept you're clever and know what you're doing.
2. Switch off the warning for the duration of the function.
3. Refactor the code. Some software houses dislike a function with more than one `return` anyway, for good reason.

I'd plump for 3 if I were you. Note that if `a` was a `double`, then the closing brace *could* be reached if the input value of `a` was `NaN`!

The science of statement reachability is a complex one. For more reading see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

I also can't resist plugging one of my answers here: [Does this function have explicit return values on all control paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467407/does-this-function-have-explicit-return-values-on-all-control-paths/46467470#46467470)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! (The first option made me laugh lol) :)