# What are the good practise about "if" "elseif" "else" statement

Tags: c++

I am not sure wether I should post this here or not, but I just had a debate about C++ good practises with a coworker today and I can't find  the point we were discussing in the CppCoreGuidelines or any forums.

We were talking about `"if" "else if" "else"` statement, and my coworker was saying that if you have a `"if - else if"` statement then you **must** put a `"else"`, even if it is empty.

For example, in his opinion, things like this is no good practise.

```
if (condition1)
{
    // Some instructions to do when condition1
    ...
}
else if (condition2)
{
    // Some instructions to do when condition2
    ...
}
```

and I should rather write this code :

```
if (condition1)
{
    // Some instructions to do when condition1
    ...
}
else if (condition2)
{
    // Some instructions to do when condition2
    ...
}
else
{
    /* Do nothing */
}
```

His main point was that just like `switch` statements must have a `default` case, `if - else if` statements must have a `else`.

I have several questions :

- is that true ?
- if yes, why ? (I don't understand the problem).
- why would some guidelines want to force that ?

Comment: "is that true ?"  - no, it isn't. It isn't true for switches either.

Comment: `else{ /* Do nothing */ }` is wasted. You wouldn't have an else statement to do nothing.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion. It's certainly not required. But you could argue that it explicitly indicates that you intended for nothing to happen in the final `else` case. It eliminates the concern that it's absence is due to an omission. I don't feel it's worth it but I can see why someone could want to push for it.

Comment: This is an opinion based question. In short, the compiler will optimise out the empty else. It's just a matter of whether or not you like having an empty else block in your code, just for your own piece of mind.

Comment: As a side note, some environments will give a warning if you switch on an enum without giving a case for each possible value. You won't get that warning if you provide a default which may or may not be desired.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux why would someone want to force that ?

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos It's not so much that it'll be "optimised out", it's more that it is just simply vacuous. There's no code to translate. It just doesn't exist in the first place, except in your source code.

Comment: @PierreBaret Like I tried to explain, there isn't zero gains in doing it. It's not much of a gain (tiny bit a clarity of intention maybe?) and it doesn't have a zero cost (extra lines, detracts from the important parts of the code). So there could be a cost vs benefit debate. I mean to say, I can imagine that someone could argue in favor of it. Someone could want to force this convention for the same reason anyone tries to force any convention. It's usually best if a code base is consistent in style.

Comment: It *can* be a good idea to in some situations to prevent program control from reaching the end of a non-`void` function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467407/does-this-function-have-explicit-return-values-on-all-control-paths. But to have an explicit "no-op" comment seems a nonsense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my coworker was saying that if you have a "if - else if" statement then you must put a "else", even if it is empty.

No style guide I have ever come across says that. And, if there is one, it's just a matter of opinion.

I do sometimes write "empty" `else` blocks, but only when they contain some interesting, useful, explanatory documenting comment about why nothing's happening in the `else` case when it might at first glance appear like a natural thing to do.

```
if (FozzieBearIsAlive())
{
   GiveMissPiggyATreat();
}
else
{
   // Miss Piggy doesn't deserve a treat, because she may
   // have killed Fozzie Bear
}
```

It's a pretty contrived example, which could otherwise be written like this:

```
// Give Miss Piggy a treat, but only if Fozzie Bear is alive
// because otherwise we might wonder whether she killed him
if (FozzieBearIsAlive())
{
   GiveMissPiggyATreat();
}
```

But sometimes the former is nicer.

Mandating that you always include some empty `else` block with nothing in it, though, is something I have not heard of and would not support.

> His main point was that just like switch statements must have a default case

Also false, except in the sense of some subjective style guide.

In fact, when switching on enums, I *discourage* `default` cases unless you functionally require one, because you prevent the compiler from warning you when you add an enumeration and forget to update all your `switch`es.

Comment: If only we knew Miss Piggy's intentions beforehand.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Unfortunately, her intentions are transmitted over UDP, and receipt is therefore not to be relied upon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's what I though, but as I am not a C++ expert, he gave me doubts about the fact that it is just purely opinion based. I can't see any code that would generate a bug due to omitting empty "else" statement.

Comment: @PierreBaret No, neither can I. I can _sort of_ understand why a really strict environment (making space rockets) might mandate this for the _complete_ avoidance of doubt ("I didn't forget an `else` statement that shouldn't be there!"), but it's silly ("oh, oops, I put the `else` statement but forgot its entire contents and nobody noticed, particularly as they are used to seeing empty `else` blocks all over the place) and you're not likely to be programming space rockets in C++ anyway. Then again, you'll come across all sorts of weird style opinions out there ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is all very personal.

> is that true ?

From a language legality perspective, no that's false.

Some guidelines might want programmers to explicitly add `else` statements but personally this sounds like an anti-pattern to me.

Comment: It is personal, but I would bet that this kind of weird requirements on "code quality" is mostly imposed by contracts between companies. For some definition of "code quality" :-)

Comment: Thing is I can't see any code snippet that would generate a bug by omitting an empty "else" statement. So this is purely opinion base, and preferences about code readability which is subjective and hase nothing to do with code efficiency or safety, am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `switch` statements do *not* require a `default` case. In fact, they may be completely empty:

```
switch (...) {
    // fine
}
```

Similarly, `if` does not require an `else`.

Some guidelines have strange rules, and some may indeed require to always have all possible branches explicitly written down in the code. However, it is *very* rare to do so, specially with branches.

I have personally seen very weird requirements out there on contracted code, so I can believe some guidelines/certification/contract/... may force it, specially older ones. My guess is that they want to be "formal" or maybe they hope it helps with "code quality" or with formal verification (if done manually, for some reason...).

Answer (score 1):

It really comes down to the coding guidelines of whatever project/company you're working for. Beyond that, it's personal preference.

For example, my current company likes to always ensure there's a `default` case for switch statements and to add the `else` clause for if statements.

Just pay attention to your company/project's guidelines and you'll be good.