# Using a return statement outside of a loop and one inside of it in a function

Tags: c++, function, loops, return

"C++ Primer" states that failing to provide a `return` after a loop that contains a `return` is an error.

Is that true? What I know is once the `return` statement is executed, the control will jump over the rest of the function back to the calling function.

So, what is the need of that `return` outside of the loop?

Comment: In case the loop completes without the `return` being executed.

Comment: C++ Primer 5th Edition - 6.3.2

Comment: I can imagine code that would not need a return after the loop, if the loop was infinite for instance. So I think that's a piece of generally good advice rather than a hard and fast rule. Basically all possible control paths through a non-void function should return a value.

Comment: please post the full quote. I can imagine that the book refers to loops that eg not necessarily have more than zero iterations, one that has a break somewhere or other control flow

Comment: I can't resist plugging this question, with my accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467407/does-this-function-have-explicit-return-values-on-all-control-paths/46467470#46467470

Comment: After the loop, put a `throw std::logic_error("should never happen");` and you ought to be good.

Answer (score 3):

If the function has a non-`void` return type, you need a `return` statement at *EVERY* possible non-exception exit point in the function's flow of execution.  That means having a `return` statement after the loop, in case the loop ends without hitting its inner `return`, eg:

```cpp
void loop1()
{
    for(...)
    {
        if (condition)
            return; // <-- function exits here
    }
    // <-- if reach here, return is optional...
}

int loop2()
{
    for(...)
    {
        if (condition)
            return ...; // <-- function exits here
    }
    return ...; // <-- if reach here, return is required...
}
```

Comment: What if I know for sure that the inner ```return``` statement is gonna be executed? Is it still an error not to provide one after the loop?

Comment: Well, in a bizarre code-design world, you *could* avoid that final `return` statement by having a `throw` statement, instead.

Comment: @Mason That's probably one of the reasons, such is reported only as a warning by the compiler.

Comment: @Mason It is fine to not have a trailing `return` if the function always returns from inside the loop.

Comment: @Mason when return type is not `void` then every path has to lead to a `return`, whether loops, or other control flow

Comment: @AdrianMole It is not that odd. For example an `at` member function could very do that if the loop searches for an element and the function specifies that it throws if it fails to find.

Comment: @Mason YOU may know the inner `return` is ALWAYS hit, but the COMPILER usually doesn't. So not having an outer `return` is a warning, not an error (unless you have configured the compiler to treat warnings as errors).  In this case, I would design the loop to `break` instead of `return` and then let the outer code `return` what it needs.

Comment: From a formal perspective, falling off the end of a function that returns a value ends up with undefined behavior. I’d you add a `return` statement to silence a warning (missing return statement) might have to remove it if you change compilers (warning: unreachable code).